# I haven’t even the strength to swing vs. I haven’t even got the strength to swing

Tags: grammar

I have a question regarding this grammatical structure I found in Portnoy's Complaint by Philip Roth, he writes that:

"I am eight, and for my birthday have received my first mitt and hardball, and a regulation bat that **I haven’t even the strength to swing** all the way around." (1969; 7)

Could somebody please help me and explain why is it possible to do that? Shouldn't the sentence look more like this? : I haven’t even **got** the strength to swing?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two issues here, that one shouldn't confound.

First, there is the question of using *got* or not whenever one uses the verb *have*. Do you say *I have a book* or *I've got a book*? Answers depend on where and by whom you are taught English, but the *meaning* of those two sentences is the same.

The second point is the placement of *even*. To make a fair comparison between the Original sentence, and a version with *got* added, I would compare:

> I haven’t even the strength to swing...
>   I haven't got even the strength to swing...

These two sentences mean the same, *even* modifies *the strength to swing all the way around*.

With *even* in a different position, you get

> I don't even have the strength to swing...
>   I haven't even got the strength to swing...

This time, *even* modifies the verb *have*.

Although very similar in meaning, there is certainly some difference in nuance between *I don't even have the strength* and *I don't have even the strength/I haven't even the strength*.